# C++ Double to Int Conversion Complication

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a cash register application in C++ which asks for the price of an item and the payment amount from the customer, where it then displays the change in dollars, quarters, dimes, and pennies:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printChange(int&, int&, int&, int&, int&);
void findCoins(int&, int&, int&, int&, int&);


int main()
{
    double price;
    double payment;
    char answer = 'y';
    int dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies;
    while(answer == 'y')
    {
        cout<<"Enter price of an item: "<<endl;
        cin>>price;
        cout<<"Enter payment from customer: "<<endl;
        cin>>payment;
        double change = payment - price;
        dollars = change;               //use implicit conversion
        change = change * 100;          //multiplication

        int coins = change - dollars * 100;
        findCoins(coins, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);

        printChange(dollars, quarters, dimes, nickels, pennies);
        cout<<"Do you have another transaction?";
        cin>>answer;
    }
    cout<<"Thanks for shopping at Albertsons!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

void printChange(int& dol, int& q, int& d, int& n, int& p)
{
    cout<<"dollars "<<dol<<endl;
    cout<<"quarters: "<<q<<endl;
    cout<<"dimes:  "<<d<<endl;
    cout<<"nickels: "<<n<<endl;
    cout<<"pennies: "<<p<<endl;
}
void findCoins(int& coins, int& quarters, int& dimes,
        int& nickels, int& pennies)
{
    quarters = coins/25;                //use implicit conversion
    dimes = coins % 25 / 10;            //use remainder division
    nickels = coins % 25 % 10 / 5;
    pennies = coins % 25 % 10 % 5;
}
```

The problem here is that I need to convert change (which is a double) into coins (which is an integer) so that I can use modulus in determining how many quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies the cashier owes the customer and no matter what angle I approach the problem I keep getting the same error - the original double value is subtracted by 1 (in some cases).

E.g.

```
Enter price of an item: 
10
Enter payment from customer: 
10.69
dollars 0
quarters: 2
dimes:  1
nickels: 1
pennies: 3
```

Compared to:

```
Enter price of an item: 
1.26
Enter payment from customer: 
5.00
dollars 3
quarters: 2
dimes:  2
nickels: 0
pennies: 4
```

NOTE: I understand that I can utilize fmod() instead of modulus for double values, but I still ran into the same type of truncation error even when changing coins into a double, specifically in the following scenario:

```
Enter price of an item: 
45
Enter payment from customer: 
47.47
dollars 2
quarters: 1
dimes:  2
nickels: 0
pennies: 1
```

Notice how I am one penny off (same issue as the first example)? I'm relatively new to C++, but I have over a year of experience in Java, and I have never run into this weird of a truncation error when converting from double to int (I understand that the decimal points are lost in certain cases, but why the subtraction of a whole double value by exactly 1 in multiple instances?)

What changes to my code, specifically, would you recommend as to prevent this annoying truncation error?

Comment: When converting money to coins, change to an integer count of the smallest unit (penny)  `penny = round(money_as_double * 100);`,  _then_ proceed to determine the various coins

Comment: Whoa dude, too much code! Read about [mcve]( http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Paul EvansThanks for the feedback will keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Round** to whole numbers.

---

Consider what values are in `payment, price, change`: 10.69, 10.00, 0.69.

Typical `double` can represent *exactly* about 2**64 different numbers.  As most `double` use a binary representation, exact decimal values of numbers like 1.23 are not in that set.  In such cases, `cin>>price` will convert text to the closest `double`.

```
text   exact double value
10.69: 10.6899999999999995026200849679298698902130126953125  
10.00: 10.00  
 0.69:  0.689999999999999946709294817992486059665679931640625
```

A key failing occurs with the below.  Let us assume that `change - dollars * 100` resulted in `68.99999999999998578914528479799628257751465`.  That value converted to `int coins` is `68` rather than the hoped for `69`.  The value was not rounded to nearest, but truncated toward zero.

```
int coins = change - dollars * 100;
```

To handle this are a number of approaches, all with pros and cons.

1. Convert FP money to *nearest* whole number amounts of the lowest fiscal unit. And then proceed with math that only uses whole numbers. (con: easy to forget to perform rounding when needed)

   ```
   const double money_base_unit = 0.01;
   double change = payment - price;
   coins = round(change/money_base_unit);
   ```
2. Begin with integer money with type `long long` in terms of some base unit like a penny. (con: trouble with overflow, money values of a fraction of the base unit, interest/rate calculations, etc.)
3. Use decimal floating point type.  (Not commonly available or slow in emulation)
4. Use fixed point type. (Even less available)
5. Use a class specifically design for money which wraps one of the above to handle financial nuances.

---

For OP, the simple solution is to round those money values properly to whole number of pennies.

Answer (score 3):

> What changes to my code, specifically, would you recommend as to prevent this annoying truncation error?

Never, ever, ever, ever, ever*100, ever<sup>1700</sup>, record monetary values with floating point values, in any programming language, for any reason.

If you're working with US Dollars, record them in Integer (preferably 64-bit integer) cents (or tenths of a cent; you'll thank me when your code gets used with gas station prices) and multiply them up to dollar amounts when you need to textually display them. Write a custom `Currency` class which will perform these conversions automatically, and will keep the internal record of the amount as an integral fixed-point number but which will convert to floating point numbers *for display only* when needed.

Comment: Using integer for money is OK for learning programs that are limited to `+,-,*`.  Integers are insufficient for interest, mortgage calculation, tips calculation, mill rates, group prices (3 for a dollar) not to mention no overflow detection.  Advice about a separate class is good.

Answer (score 0):

@xirema is right, 
The error mainly is in this line

```
int coins = change - dollars * 100;
```

Although its legit, and change = 69 and dollars = 0, but after it coins will be 68.

Don't do this, and better use int.

IF you want to fix this for now, here is the bad way to do it.

```
float dcoins = change - (dollars * 100);
    int coins = dcoins;
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Xirema's answer, if you need an example of things you might consider when writing a currency class you can use my post on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85835/storing-currency-precision-values) for reference.

I'd probably chop this specific problem up to doing `change - dollars * 100`, where the integer cast doesn't round by default.